# How do i create a share-link for viadeo?

Tags: href, social-media, viadeo

so I have to create a viadeo-share-link.

Every old tutorial I found is no longer valid, i guess they have changed the whole structure here so the old "http://www.viadeo.com/shareit/share/?title=title&overview=description&url=url" is no longer valid.

I googled it but I can only find sone thired-party services which i deffinetly don't want to use.
And the questions here (on Stackoverflow) are older with the old links.

The Website of viadeo is not helpful here as well...

dose someone have the new URL I can use here?

Answer (score 0):

OK found the answer, (they only provided a french text... thanks for that)
Viadeo disabled any APIs and any possibilities to share a link there.
You can't share links, applications or articles there anymore which therefore made the ability to create a share-link obsolete.

https://viadeo.zendesk.com/hc/fr/articles/360013905779-L-offre-Viadeo-%C3%A9volue-

TLDR: got removed